# Stuck with texture paint: why can't I see the full material to paint on

Tags: materials, texture-painting

So, yes, I am fairly new to Blender and I'm following a tutorial and got stuck. I recognize that this texturing tutorial was above my knowledge but now I just want to finish this model and move on, mostly because I am stubborn, so please bear with me.

I have the Skin material used in the tutorial (it was a part of the .blend file) but when I go to texture paint mode I cannot see the layer/image on which I need to paint.

Any ideas what I can do go get myself out of this? What am I missing? The 1st photo is from the tutorial and the 2nd is my file.

[image: This is how the tutorial files looks like and you can see the Skin Details material]

[image: And this is my mess.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thank u so much 4 the comments. In my head it sounded a lot clearer. After spending much time on this, I found the solution. I was operating under the assumption that he was painting on a map that was already included in the material by default (the Skin details one). So, I kept looking for it, inserted the material over and over and kept thinking I had toggled something and could not see it. Well, it turned out that he most likely created a new image texture using the same base color, plugged that in the Principled BSDF and then painted details over it. This is the only way it worked for me.